# TabLayout's setOnTabSelectedListener is conflict with its setupWithViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I use TabLayout with ViewPager, also, I have to listen to the TabReselected event, but it seems that they are conflict:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(...);
mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "selected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "reselected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
});
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

it seems that when I use setupWithViewPager(mViewPager), the Listener added before will be invalid.  The key is I need do other things when the tab was [[reselected]], but how?

Answer (score 1):

//  use runnable as it takes time to setup with the viewpager :

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewpagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "selected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "reselected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes, it works. but there are side effects come out.  When I swipe the ViewPager, everything is ok; But if I click the tab, normally, it will change the content, but here we have to call "viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()"  in onTabSelected function, the point is if we do it this way,  the onTabReselected function is also called.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, first you need to call

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(onBoardVP);
```

And then in `onTabSelected()` method, add `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());`

Just like this:

```
@Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "selected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }
```

Comment: @Spykaran is correct, although some side effects.  As I wrote in the question, the `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(onBoardVP); `  will make setOnTabSelectedListener defined earlier not work.  if we use `setOnTabSelectedListener ` after `setupWithViewPager`, then it seems `setupWithViewPager` will not work. Maybe I am not clear, thx

Comment: Yes. If setupWithViewPager() is executed before setting tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(), setupWithViewPager() wont work. I mean when you tap on the tabs, fragments in viewpager won't switch. Thats the reason why I have put mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); inside onTabSelected() method to make the switching work on tab tapping.